# Segmentation fault by TensorFlow with GPU

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow

I have been training CNN using TensorFlow Python API on a corporate server, which was initially running. On the second day, it started throwing this error: Segmentation fault. In order to isolate this, I simply tried creating just a TensorFlow session, but it threw the same error: Segmentation fault

One more thing I have observed is that typically TensorFlow determines the number of GPUs available in the host, but when the problem occurred it only showed a single GPU as being available despite the fact there were over 4 GPUs simply resting. It is my impression that someone has capped it's limits or applied some sort of restriction. Before I make a talk with them, I would like to first know, at least for myself what could be it that causes segmentation fault.

Please share your opinions. Thank you

Comment: I think this is related to your CUDA and CuDNN. Did you install from source code or from whl file? Could reinstall/recompile with CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v4?

Comment: To debug segmentation fault it's useful to get a stack trace (ie, run the program under gdb)

Comment: @Sung Kim: I do not know how the management installed them on the server as it was there already, and also I am not authorised to reinstall or make changes to their system libraries. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: Thank you for your comment. I am unsure what you mean by program. However, I would like to emphasise that an attempt to creating a TensorFlow session failed in the first place, so I wonder how to debug that. Either way, since you have mentioned gdb, I will check it now. In the meantime, could you let me know whether turning on exclusive mode in GPU could cause this segmentation fault ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see many segmentation faults, so, no idea. But generally any kind of deviation from a common configuration has a potential to trigger new bugs. In particular, if the GPU is visible in nvidia-smi, I think TensorFlow will try to use it